Display having spikes/glitches
I installed Ubuntu 2 days ago and my display is glitching (the screen goes right and back to the starting position and it gets a lot darker, but readable not fully turning off)
I don't know what information to leave..I have used Ubuntu on this hardware before.
Now I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
